# Can't run any Android Project from clean Ubuntu 14.04 Installation

Tags: android, ubuntu, 64-bit

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit and now I can't start any of my old Android Projects neither from Android Studio nor from the ADT Eclipse Bundle. Even a clean newly created project in either of these two IDEs fails to load on my phone (I did not change anything on the phone). The log from logcat just loops endlessly the following stuff, which I think in essence says "VM aborting" and "A/libc Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)" and a warning "JNI WARNING: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal continuation byte 0x5f"

```
04-21 17:59:06.625  24805-24805/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-21 17:59:06.645    1720-1720/? D/Zygote﹕ Process 24792 terminated by signal (11)
04-21 17:59:06.735    2152-2173/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 798K, 25% free 12012K/15908K, paused 137ms, total 138ms
04-21 17:59:06.735    2152-3338/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.example.test_64 for activity com.example.test_64/.MainActivity: pid=24805 uid=10118 gids={50118, 1028}
04-21 17:59:06.755  24805-24805/? W/dalvikvm﹕ JNI WARNING: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal continuation byte 0x5f
04-21 17:59:06.755  24805-24805/? W/dalvikvm﹕ string: 'en_Latn_US_�_DE'
04-21 17:59:06.755  24805-24805/? W/dalvikvm﹕ in Llibcore/icu/ICU;.addLikelySubtags:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; (NewStringUTF)
04-21 17:59:06.755  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
04-21 17:59:06.755  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40df19a0 self=0x400f8010
04-21 17:59:06.755  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ | sysTid=24805 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1074991580
04-21 17:59:06.755  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ | state=R schedstat=( 35461432 22644041 75 ) utm=0 stm=3 core=0
04-21 17:59:06.765  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #00  pc 000012a0  /system/lib/libcorkscrew.so (unwind_backtrace_thread+27)
04-21 17:59:06.765  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #01  pc 0005fb74  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpNativeStack(DebugOutputTarget const*, int)+35)
04-21 17:59:06.765  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #02  pc 000539ca  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThreadEx(DebugOutputTarget const*, Thread*, bool)+313)
04-21 17:59:06.765  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #03  pc 00053a72  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThread(Thread*, bool)+25)
04-21 17:59:06.765  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #04  pc 00038996  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #05  pc 00039d54  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #06  pc 0003bf82  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #07  pc 00015f3e  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #08  pc 00016354  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #09  pc 0001e490  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #10  pc 0004d26c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+395)
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #11  pc 000278a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #12  pc 0002b7d8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+176)
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #13  pc 0005fd76  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+373)
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #14  pc 00067810  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #15  pc 000278a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #16  pc 0002b7d8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+176)
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #17  pc 0005faa0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+271)
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #18  pc 00049856  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #19  pc 0004773a  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #20  pc 000483e6  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+389)
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #21  pc 00000db6  /system/bin/app_process
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ #22  pc 00012728  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+35)
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at libcore.icu.ICU.addLikelySubtags(Native Method)
04-21 17:59:06.775  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.text.TextUtils.getLayoutDirectionFromLocale(TextUtils.java:1724)
04-21 17:59:06.785  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.content.res.Configuration.setLayoutDirection(Configuration.java:1313)
04-21 17:59:06.785  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.content.res.Configuration.updateFrom(Configuration.java:811)
04-21 17:59:06.785  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.applyConfigurationToResourcesLocked(ActivityThread.java:3958)
04-21 17:59:06.785  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4387)
04-21 17:59:06.785  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:153)
04-21 17:59:06.785  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
04-21 17:59:06.785  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-21 17:59:06.785  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-21 17:59:06.785  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
04-21 17:59:06.785  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 17:59:06.785  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-21 17:59:06.785  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
04-21 17:59:06.785  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
04-21 17:59:06.785  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-21 17:59:06.785  24805-24805/? I/dalvikvm﹕ [ 04-21 17:59:06.785 24805:24805 E/dalvikvm ]
    VM aborting
04-21 17:59:06.785  24805-24805/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 24805 (example.test_64)
04-21 17:59:06.886  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-21 17:59:06.886  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'samsung/cm_golden/golden:4.2.2/JDQ39E/eng.maclaw.20130908.135703:userdebug/test-keys'
04-21 17:59:06.886  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '106'
04-21 17:59:06.886  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 24805, tid: 24805, name: example.test_64  >>> com.example.test_64 <<<
04-21 17:59:06.886  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadd00d
04-21 17:59:07.006  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 deadd00d  r3 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.006  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ r4 408bd1f8  r5 0000020c  r6 00000075  r7 4089d463
04-21 17:59:07.006  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8 4089d365  r9 00054878  sl 000548c8  fp 408bd1f8
04-21 17:59:07.006  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ ip 00000001  sp be846190  lr 401f936d  pc 40853a74  cpsr 60070030
04-21 17:59:07.006  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ d0  74726f6261204d56  d1  726174536576696e
04-21 17:59:07.006  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ d2  0000000000000075  d3  000000000000006c
04-21 17:59:07.006  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ d4  725f64696f72646e  d5  732e656d69746e75
04-21 17:59:07.006  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ d6  6f72646e6128206f  d7  72646e413a3a6469
04-21 17:59:07.006  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
04-21 17:59:07.006  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
04-21 17:59:07.006  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
04-21 17:59:07.006  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
04-21 17:59:07.006  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ d16 0000000000000001  d17 0000000000000001
04-21 17:59:07.006  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ d18 00000000d239b6f1  d19 0000000000000000
04-21 17:59:07.006  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ d20 3fc554e7eb0eb47c  d21 3e66376972bea4d0
04-21 17:59:07.006  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ d22 3f4de16b9c24a98f  d23 3fb0f4a31edab38b
04-21 17:59:07.016  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ d24 3fede16b9c24a98f  d25 3fe55559ee5e69f9
04-21 17:59:07.016  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
04-21 17:59:07.016  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
04-21 17:59:07.016  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
04-21 17:59:07.016  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ scr 60000010
04-21 17:59:07.016  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
04-21 17:59:07.016  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  pc 00045a74  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+75)
04-21 17:59:07.016  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  pc 00039d55  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:07.016  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02  pc 0003bf83  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:07.026  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #03  pc 00015f41  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
04-21 17:59:07.026  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #04  pc 00016355  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
04-21 17:59:07.026  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #05  pc 0001e490  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
04-21 17:59:07.026  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #06  pc 0004d26d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+396)
04-21 17:59:07.026  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #07  pc 000278a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:07.026  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #08  pc 0002b7d8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+176)
04-21 17:59:07.026  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #09  pc 0005fd77  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+374)
04-21 17:59:07.026  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #10  pc 00067811  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:07.026  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #11  pc 000278a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:07.026  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #12  pc 0002b7d8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+176)
04-21 17:59:07.026  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #13  pc 0005faa1  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
04-21 17:59:07.026  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #14  pc 00049857  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:07.026  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #15  pc 0004773d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
04-21 17:59:07.026  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #16  pc 000483e7  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+390)
04-21 17:59:07.026  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #17  pc 00000db7  /system/bin/app_process
04-21 17:59:07.026  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #18  pc 0001272b  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+38)
04-21 17:59:07.026  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #19  pc 00000ae8  /system/bin/app_process
04-21 17:59:07.026  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ stack:
04-21 17:59:07.026  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846150  00000001
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846154  402241b4  /system/lib/libc.so
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846158  402241b4  /system/lib/libc.so
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be84615c  402241b4  /system/lib/libc.so
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846160  402241b4  /system/lib/libc.so
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846164  401f936d  /system/lib/libc.so (__sflush_locked+36)
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846168  4022424c  /system/lib/libc.so
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be84616c  402241b4  /system/lib/libc.so
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846170  00000000
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846174  401fa33d  /system/lib/libc.so (_fwalk+32)
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846178  408bd1f8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be84617c  0000020c
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846180  00000075
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846184  4089d463  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846188  df0027ad
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be84618c  00000000
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  be846190  00000000
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846194  6c756e28
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846198  0000296c
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be84619c  00000000
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8461a0  00000000
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8461a4  00000000
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8461a8  00000000
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8461ac  00000000
04-21 17:59:07.036  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8461b0  00000000
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8461b4  00000000
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8461b8  00000000
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8461bc  00000000
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8461c0  00000000
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8461c4  00000000
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8461c8  00000000
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8461cc  00000000
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ ........  ........
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  be8463a8  be8463dc  [stack]
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8463ac  00000000
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8463b0  be8463f3  [stack]
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8463b4  00000004
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8463b8  be8464cc  [stack]
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8463bc  4089d461  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8463c0  408bd1f8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8463c4  40227228
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8463c8  00000003
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8463cc  4089d33c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8463d0  be846484  [stack]
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8463d4  be8464cc  [stack]
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8463d8  00000000
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8463dc  4089d400  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8463e0  be846400  [stack]
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8463e4  40847d47  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ ........  ........
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02  be846480  be8464cc  [stack]
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846484  40de1830  [heap]
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846488  408b3382  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be84648c  40de1830  [heap]
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846490  408b30d0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846494  00000020
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846498  40de1801  [heap]
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be84649c  40227228
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8464a0  40227228
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8464a4  9a80001d
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8464a8  40de1830  [heap]
04-21 17:59:07.046  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8464ac  58c3ef43  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
04-21 17:59:07.056  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r4:
04-21 17:59:07.056  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd1d8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.056  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd1e8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.056  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd1f8 40de1860 40de1850 00800000 10000000
04-21 17:59:07.056  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd208 04000000 00000000 00000000 3fe80000
04-21 17:59:07.056  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd218 00200000 00800000 00004000 00006000
04-21 17:59:07.056  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd228 00000001 00000101 00000002 00000001
04-21 17:59:07.056  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd238 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000002
04-21 17:59:07.066  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd248 000001f4 402786c1 402790d5 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.066  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd258 402786ad 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.066  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd268 40de1a90 00000000 00000002 00000003
04-21 17:59:07.066  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd278 00000001 00000001 00010100 00000100
04-21 17:59:07.066  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd288 00000000 40de19c0 00000003 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.066  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd298 40de19b0 400f8db8 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.066  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd2a8 40de1f30 50000ab1 400c6008 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.066  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd2b8 400cadd0 400cadf0 40de21e8 40de22a8
04-21 17:59:07.066  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd2c8 40de2350 40de23f8 40de24a0 40de2548
04-21 17:59:07.066  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r7:
...
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near r9:
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054858 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054868 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054878 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054888 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054898 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 000548a8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 000548b8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 000548c8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 000548d8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 000548e8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 000548f8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054908 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054918 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054928 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054938 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054948 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near sl:
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 000548a8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 000548b8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 000548c8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 000548d8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 000548e8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 000548f8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054908 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054918 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054928 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054938 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054948 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054958 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054968 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054978 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054988 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 00054998 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near fp:
04-21 17:59:07.076  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd1d8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd1e8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd1f8 40de1860 40de1850 00800000 10000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd208 04000000 00000000 00000000 3fe80000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd218 00200000 00800000 00004000 00006000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd228 00000001 00000101 00000002 00000001
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd238 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000002
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd248 000001f4 402786c1 402790d5 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd258 402786ad 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd268 40de1a90 00000000 00000002 00000003
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd278 00000001 00000001 00010100 00000100
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd288 00000000 40de19c0 00000003 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd298 40de19b0 400f8db8 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd2a8 40de1f30 50000ab1 400c6008 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd2b8 400cadd0 400cadf0 40de21e8 40de22a8
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 408bd2c8 40de2350 40de23f8 40de24a0 40de2548
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory near sp:
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846170 00000000 401fa33d 408bd1f8 0000020c
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846180 00000075 4089d463 df0027ad 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846190 00000000 6c756e28 0000296c 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8461a0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8461b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8461c0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8461d0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8461e0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be8461f0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846200 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846210 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846220 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846230 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846240 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846250 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be846260 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around pc:
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40853a54 447a34cc e966f7d8 461d2300 b1525d1a
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40853a64 18ad3301 7f00f5b3 e004d1f8 4a0a4798
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40853a74 f7d87015 490ce95e 4a0c2006 44794c0c
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40853a84 f7d8447a 447ce800 f7d82000 6de3e8aa
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40853a94 d1eb2b00 bf00e7eb deadd00d 000650ae
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40853aa4 000697a4 000497d9 00048bb4 0004a9fa
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40853ab4 0006976a 4605b530 b08b4c15 462aa803
04-21 17:59:07.086  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40853ac4 447c4914 68236824 93094479 f9c9f009
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40853ad4 aa0a2100 1d20f842 f0099808 b958fded
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40853ae4 462b9802 4a0d490c 20069000 447a4479
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40853af4 efc8f7d7 ff96f7ff f7f2a803 9a09ff79
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40853b04 428a6821 f7d7d001 b00beffa bf00bd30
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40853b14 0006501e 0004a9be 00048b46 0004a9a1
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40853b24 1a55b5f8 4617460e 46041c69 eeacf7e5
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40853b34 696042b7 4631d004 f7d7462a 1940efaa
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 40853b44 61202300 bdf87003 4604b538 6120460d
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ code around lr:
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 401f934c 447e4e08 68336836 f000b10b 4620fa4c
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 401f935c ffccf7ff 68304605 4620b110 fa50f000
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 401f936c bd704628 0002abee 4604b570 4811b928
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 401f937c e8bd4478 f0004070 4e0fbfcb 6836447e
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 401f938c b10b6833 fa2ff000 f01089a0 d1060f18
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 401f939c fdacf7f1 f04f2109 600135ff 4620e003
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 401f93ac ffa4f7ff 68324605 4620b112 fa28f000
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 401f93bc bd704628 ffffffc9 0002abb4 44794909
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 401f93cc 680b6809 6843b963 2a001e5a da016042
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 401f93dc bba6f001 f8116801 6001cb01 47704660
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 401f93ec bff4f000 0002ab72 47f0e92d 4f3e4604
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 401f93fc 447f4688 683b683f f000b10b 6860f9f4
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 401f940c dc042800 f0014620 2800fad7 6826d15f
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 401f941c 6865210a 462a4630 fc1cf7fb 3001b168
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 401f942c c00cf8b4 f8c81b81 68621000 5300f44c
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ 401f943c 1a5381a3 0009e884 4606e043 f1056ca0
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ memory map around fault addr deadd00d:
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ be826000-be847000 [stack]
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ (no map for address)
04-21 17:59:07.096  21813-21813/? I/DEBUG﹕ ffff0000-ffff1000 [vectors]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after all I notices no old applications from me were working anymore on the phone itself, which is strange because almost everything else from the play store continued working.

After a factory reset everything worked again. Not sure what happened, but the phone had a crash a few days ago where it went completely black suddenly while writing a text message. Maybe that corrupted something on the phone.